# How to get Child elements in Karate framework

Tags: karate

I need to extract child elements from response of one api and then pass it dynamically to next api request.

Suppose i have the below xml:

```
* def foo =
"""
<records>
  <record index="1">a</record>
  <record index="2">b</record>
  <record index="3" foo="bar">c</record>
</records>
"""
```

I want to extract only this:

```
  <record index="1">a</record>
  <record index="2">b</record>
  <record index="3" foo="bar">c</record>
```

I tried below options, but none of then worked:

```
* def chk = foo//records/*
* def chk = foo//records/child::*
* def chk = foo//records/descendant::*
* print chk
```

After printing, I get the below, please suggest if i'm missing anything or any other way to do it.Thank you!

```
13:51:07.046 INFO  - [print] {
  "records": {
    "record": [
      {
        "_": "a",
        "@": {
          "index": "1"
        }
      },
      {
        "_": "b",
        "@": {
          "index": "2"
        }
      },
      {
        "_": "c",
        "@": {
          "foo": "bar",
          "index": "3"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: looks like a simple string replace would do the trick if all you need to do is take a set of elements and stuff them into another XML template: 
(I'm leaving the original longer answer at the end of this answer for reference)

```
* def foo =
"""
<records>
  <record index="1">a</record>
  <record index="2">b</record>
  <record index="3" foo="bar">c</record>
</records>
"""
* replace foo.<records> = ''
* replace foo.</records> = ''
# you can do def bar = read('template.txt') in your case
* text bar = 
"""
<after new="namespace">
  @@foo@@
</after>
"""
* replace bar.@@foo@@ = foo
* xml bar = bar
* match bar ==
"""
<after new="namespace">
  <record index="1">a</record>
  <record index="2">b</record>
  <record index="3" foo="bar">c</record>
</after>
"""
```

Yes, Karate does not support an XML node-list natively, typically you don't need it. And XML has this peculiarity where you always need a "parent" or "wrapping" element.

As you see above, you do have all the information needed. I'm still not clear what kind of XML you need to pass to the next API - but whatever the case, there is a way in Karate. Here are 2 options. First, iterating over the data and manually emitting XML:

```
* def foo =
"""
<records>
  <record index="1">a</record>
  <record index="2">b</record>
  <record index="3" foo="bar">c</record>
</records>
"""

* json records = foo.records.record
* def temp = <bar></bar>
* def fun = 
"""
function(r, i){ 
  karate.set('temp', '/bar/record[' + (i+1) + ']', r._); 
  karate.set('temp', '/bar/record[' + (i+1) + ']/@index', r['@'].index); 
}
"""
* eval karate.forEach(records, fun)
* match temp == 
"""
<bar>
  <record index="1">a</record>
  <record index="2">b</record>
  <record index="3">c</record>
</bar>
"""
```

Note that `karate.forEach` is available only in the upcoming 0.8.0 but you can try 0.8.0.RC3

Here's another interesting option, if all you need to do is change the XML parent, a string replace will do the trick:

```
* replace foo.<records> = '<bar>'
* replace foo.</records> = '</bar>'
* xml bar = foo
* match bar ==
"""
<bar>
  <record index="1">a</record>
  <record index="2">b</record>
  <record index="3" foo="bar">c</record>
</bar>
"""
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response as always! I wanted this as the namespace of the parent element changes in the subsequent request, i had written one js function and using it like this:                   * def resp = get response //*[local-name()="records"]
* xmlstring holder = resp
* xml newRecords= replacer (holder,/n1/g,"n2")

Comment: @nagpai I would say you are on the right track with a string replace.but wouldn't a `set` have worked `* set response /records/@foo = 'bar'`

Comment: Additional information: In the nextrequest.xml this is defined as         #(newRecords).I wanted to somehow avoid this namespace replacement as I read the request from a file with required name space and then karate can just replace child elements(count is not static) based on the previous response.

Comment: @nagpai then maybe the karate string `replace` may be the solution. you already know how to convert xml to string. take that string and use a placeholder in another string: https://github.com/intuit/karate#replace, convert back to xml if needed

Comment: Thank you Peter, this is more simpler.