# karate xpath - Can we replace/delete a node

Tags: karate

I'm looking to test error messages by modifying a valid xml message file.
I can easily add nodes like this in the scenario:

`* def invalidDocumentId = read('Valid.xml')
* set invalidDocumentId /soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body = <tis:extraBonus>Extra</tis:extraBonus>
    Given request invalidDocumentId`

But I'd like to also remove nodes, update node names, change attribute names.
Is there a way to set that or do I need to call Java com.intuit.karate.XmlUtils.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, removing and adding a node and even attributes should be easy, just use the `remove` and `set` keywords with XPath. They will over-write values if needed.

```
* def base = <query><name>foo</name></query>
* remove base /query/name
* match base == <query/>
* set base /query/foo = 'bar'
* set base /query/@baz = 'ban'
* match base == <query baz="ban"><foo>bar</foo></query>
```

And the good news is that if you have some *really* tricky XML manipulation requirements, the string `replace` syntax comes to the rescue.  This is best explained in this other answer on Stack Overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50367134/143475 | https://stackoverflow.com/a/53682733/143475

Comment: Thanks for the quick response :) That covers most of what I'm trying to do. My last sticking point is when there is a namespace in the node I'm trying to rename {* def base = <tis:query xmlns:tis="http://www.somewhere/service/addPerson"><tis:person><tis:name>foo</tis:name></tis:person></tis:query> * replace base.<tis:query xmlns:tis="http://www.somewhere/service/addPerson"> = '<tis:mary>'
* replace base.</tis:query> = '</tis:mary>' Given request base}This results in a syntax error that I think relates to the quote marks for the namespace in the replace

Comment: @TimFeltham since you are new to Stack Overflow, please consider marking the answer as accepted. hmm, if you have a namespace perhaps the cleaner way is to as a first step knock that attribute out of the way using `remove`

Comment: remove doesn't seem to work for attributes... * remove base /query/@xmlns:tis       doesn't produce an error but doesn't remove the attribute

Comment: ... and as a workaround, look at the long / complete answer at the other question linked to above

Comment: @TimFeltham not being able to remove an XML attribute is a bug and is just fixed. will be in the next version, but we should be able to release an RC5 soon. thanks for discovering this ! https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/407

Comment: @TimFeltham this is available as a test release - can you try version 0.8.0.RC6