# How to add elements / attributes to xml file in karate

Tags: karate

I have an xml file that I need to add new attributes during the test run in karate but I am having difficulty.

I need to add the commented lines:

```
    <HotelReservations>
                <HotelReservation CreateDateTime="#(setup.timestamp)" CreatorID="LMS" ResStatus="Reserved">
                    <UniqueID ID="#(setup.resId)" Type="10">
                        <CompanyName />
                    </UniqueID>
                    <RoomStays>
                        <RoomStay MarketCode="" PromotionCode="" SourceOfBusiness="">
                            <RoomRates>
                                <RoomRate InvBlockCode="#(vendorInfo.blockCode)" NumberOfUnits="1" RatePlanCode="" RoomTypeCode="#(vendorInfo.roomType)">\
<!--                                    <Rates>-->
<!--                                        <Rate EffectiveDate="2021-01-11" ExpireDate="2021-04-12" RateTimeUnit="Day">-->
<!--                                            <Base AmountBeforeTax="149.00" CurrencyCode="USD"/>-->
<!--                                        </Rate>-->
<!--                                        <Rate EffectiveDate="2023-04-14" ExpireDate="2023-04-15" RateTimeUnit="Day">-->
<!--                                            <Base AmountBeforeTax="159.00" CurrencyCode="USD"/>-->
<!--                                        </Rate>-->
<!--                                    </Rates>-->
                                </RoomRate>
                            </RoomRates>
                            <GuestCounts>
                                <GuestCount AgeQualifyingCode="10" Count="1" />
                            </GuestCounts>
```

Comment: if all else fails, use a replace as in the linked question. also see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50615950/143475